# Virtualizing iOS on Ubuntu

Tags: virtualization, ios

I see that this has been asked before, but not for several years.

Is there any way to virtualize iOS on Ubuntu?

Comment: To be clear, this is about Apple iOS and not Cisco iOS, right?

Comment: Hi @dobey: how's this for a fast response? Yes, I meant Apple iOS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not possible to install iOS on VirtualBox because iOS is only for ARM-based processors, and VirtualBox does not support hardware emulation of the ARM architecture. Unlike Android, iOS isn't open source so you can't recompile it for x86 processors. Plus, you'd need to write a custom boot loader for iOS somehow.

A company called [Corellium](https://twitter.com/CorelliumHQ) is claiming to be the first business to offer a virtualized iOS device experience to developers and testers. The company is defining this as the "future of mobile development" which will give developers instant access to run their creations on virtualized iPhones and iPads on a Mac or PC which are running actual real versions of iOS. Corellium is for developers, not for ordinary users.

Comment: Thanks. Read about the architecture issues after posting this.